# How to run python script Using apache camel?

Tags: java, python, apache-camel

I need to run python script using apache camel,I used exec end point for same

What I tried

```
          from("direct:start").to("exec:cmd?args=python D:\\source\\test.py")
```

Comment: any error/exception?

Comment: no...program runs without any error

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet you have mentioned - looks like you are executing command cmd with python as input. That doesn't sound perfect. cmd shouldn't be taking any input arguments. Instead try the following:

```
      from("direct:start").to("exec:python?args=D:\\source\\test.py")
```

And make sure that you have python installed and this snippet

```
      python D:\\source\\test.py
```

is what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I already try with this solution .But Nothing is happing. :(   and yes I have python installed